# Showing popup in the new Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, fbconnect

I used to have an `href` in my website. When users clicked on it, a multi-friend selector showed so they could invite their friends to my website.
That was done using the following code:

```
 FB.ensureInit(function() {
        var dialog = new FB.UI.FBMLPopupDialog('XXXXXXX', '');
        var fbml = 'Multi-Friend-Selector FBML'
        dialog.setFBMLContent(fbml);
        dialog.setContentWidth(620);
        dialog.setContentHeight(570);
        dialog.show();
    });
```

Now, I'm using the new JavaScript SDK (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js), but the old methods are not present...
How can I do it with the new SDK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, finally got the irritating box to resize from the original 964 pixels:

For compatibility (let's hope it will get fixed in the future, or documented better)
I still say

```
size:(width:600,height:500),
```

but then I break out width and height as properties of parent object, so in the end use:

```
size:(width:600,height:500),width:600,height:500, ...
```

And now it's also resizable with the JavaScript library of your choice, that is, here's a sample with jQuery resizing:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'fbml.dialog',
    fbml: (
         '<div style="width:480px;border:1px black solid;">A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
         'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
         'social graph and distribution power to your site.</div>'
       ),
    size: {width:640,height:480}, width:640, height:480
});
$(".FB_UI_Dialog").css('width', $(window).width()*0.8); // 80% of window width
// I'm also sure you could stack this call if you wanted to
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after 2 days (because I'm not a JavaScript expert :P ) of reading the open source Facebook JavaScript SDK, I found a method:

```
FB.ui({
            method : 'fbml.dialog',
            fbml: '<fb:fbml>' +
                  '<fb:request-form action=......',
        });
```

It looks simple, yes I know, but now the problem is when I send the invitation, I get a new tab opened leaving the "dialog" (in Facebook terms, because popup means another thing for them!!) open!

So I am still struggeling, but I will find the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me..

```
FB.ui({method:'fbml.dialog', fbml:'<fb:request-form action="URL" method="post" invite="true" type="TYPE" content="THIS IS THE MESSAGE <fb:req-choice url=\'URL\'label=\'Accept\' />" <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="REQUEST FORM TITLE" /> </fb:request-form>'})});
```

Replace the CAPS with your content.

The only problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to resize the dialog to fit the content.  It stays at 964px.  I've tried many versions of

```
size:(width:600,height:500),
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: unfortunately no, I still have these 2 problems:
1) After invitation, a new window is opened
2) Dialog size !!

Answer (score 1):

I just do this.
 FB.ui({ method: 'fbml.dialog', **width: 500, height: 300,** fbml:......

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers were working for me.
The workaround I found was to do the following:

```
var uiSize = FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size;
FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = {width:760, height:450};

FB.ui({
    method:'fbml.dialog',
    display: 'popup',                   
    fbml: message
},
    function( response ){
        FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = uiSize;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, but please note the following:

- The width and height refer to the dialog-box itself, WITHOUT the "faded" thick blue border.
- The width + height appear in the following code in 3 places.
- The COLS and ROWS attribute match the size in the following example - 625x515 pixels.
- Since IE sucks, I had to use jQuery with $.browser to force a POP-UP in IE.

Hope this helps :)

```
function fb_invite_friends() {
    FB.ui({method:'fbml.dialog', display:($.browser.msie ? 'popup' : 'dialog'), size:{width:625,height:515}, width:625, height:515, fbml:'<fb:request-form action="http://yoursite.com/" method="POST" invite="true" type="DayBox" content="Would you like to check out YOUR-SITE App too? <fb:req-choice url=\'http://apps.facebook.com/your-site/\' label=\'Yes\' />" <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use DayBox" cols=5 rows=3 bypass="cancel" email_invite="true" import_external_friends="false" /> </fb:request-form>'});
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Facebook */
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: fb_app_id, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        if (facebook_canvas) {
            FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(4000); // Will resize the iFrame every 4000ms
        }
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            // The user clicked "LIKE", so we give him more coins!
            $.get(href_url, {action:'log_likes'});
        });
        // FBML Dialog size fix
        FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = {width:625, height:515};
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add display: 'dialog' and it will resize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <script>
  var uiSize = FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size;
FB.UIServer.Methods["fbml.dialog"].size = {width:999};

  var dialog = {
    method: 'fbml.dialog',
    display: 'dialog',
    fbml: '<fb:request-form action="http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxx" method="post" target="_top" invite="true" type="Contest" content="Come and Join this contest!"> <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" max="30" import_external_friends="false" email_invite="false" cols="5" actiontext="Invite your friends!" /></fb:request-form>',
  };
  FB.ui(dialog,function(response) {
        alert("fbDialogDismiss();");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that someone need help with application request and friend invitation here is facebook docs about that: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
and piece of code that you need is:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'A request especially for one person.', data: 'tracking information for the user'});
```