# Facebook Javascript SDK change friend selector submit button text

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript UI method to show a friend selector dialog. However, because my app doesn't actually send invites to the selected friends, the text of the submit button is "Send Requests" is very misleading. Is there anyway I can change this text while still using a Facebook API?

I'm using
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

and have also tried
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I think that including [fb:req-choice](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/req-choice/) into the FBML of your UI could do the trick.

Example code can be seen here:
[Showing popup in the new Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713379/showing-popup-in-the-new-facebook-javascript-sdk)

Comment: I've looked through every post on that thread. none of them mention the api I said i was using: FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',..



only a few of them contain req-choice, and this is within the message sent in the request to the friend (which is not what i want to do). where is the example you are referring to?

Comment: Yep, you are right about that it's to change the wrong button. However they talk about FB.ui, which is JS SDK. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't know how you can change the button to SEND requests. Regards